# ssh forwardagent with 2 idenities

Tags: github, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm trying to push changes to a clients github account from their server using ForwardingAgent, but my id_rsa_corevm identity isn't being forwarded.

In my ~/.ssh/config file I have this

```
Host corevm
        Hostname 192.168.56.101
        User user1
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_corevm
        ForwardAgent yes

macbook-pro:.ssh macuser$ ssh-add -l
######## /Users/macuser/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
######## /Users/macuser/.ssh/id_rsa_corevm (RSA)
```

When I ssh into their server and test the ssh connection to github, I see my id_rsa_corevm identity but still can't connect to the clients github account.

```
[user1@corevm ~]$ ssh -t -vv git@github.com

debug2: key: /Users/macuser/.ssh/id_rsa (#####)
debug2: key: /Users/macuser/.ssh/id_rsa_corevm (######)
```

I only see one 'Offering public key' and not my id_rsa_corevm.

```
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/macuser/.ssh/id_rsa

Hi githubuser! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

The success message means my default id_rsa file IS being forwarded and I can connect to my own github account.

Then I try to push a change to the clients github, I get permission denied.

```
[user1@corevm test]$ git push origin master
ERROR: Permission to clientgithubuser/test.git denied to githubuser.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I would prefer to just add my id_rsa.pub to my clients github account, but apparently github does not allow sharing of keys.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about creating seperate users and sudo ing as a different user when wishing to push ti github

Comment: you mean add another user on my mac and ssh from that account? yeah, that would probably work.

Comment: Just looked up osx has sudo so lookup no password sudo get that working so from user1 u sudo user2 -c run command. Then u can script task